# node.js express routing url for POST / adding content to a specific user page

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, node.js, express

I need to figure out the correct route for my node.js express project. I am creating a health app for a trainer to manager his clients. The trainer can access individual client profiles and click on "Tasklist" button to access their exercise list. On the Exercise List page, I need to be able to add an exercise to the list below it.

The tricky part is the routing and URL to add an exercise to that user's Exercise List.

**tasks.js POST where problem lies, specifically the redirect routes: Is this a possibility for the redirect routes?

```
----[[[[ res.redirect('user/' + _id +  '/tasklist');  ]]]]

/* POST new exercise */
router.post('/user/:_id/tasklist/add', function(req, res, next){

    var _id = req.params._id;
    console.log("Add task for user id " + _id)

    if (!req.user || !req.body || !req.body.text) {
        //no task text info, redirect to home page with flash message
        req.flash('error', 'please enter an exercise');
        res.redirect('user/:_id/tasklist');
    }

    else {

        // Insert into db. New tasks are assumed to be not completed.
        var dateCreated = new Date();
        // Create a new Task, an instance of the Task schema, and call save()
        new Task( { user: _id , text: req.body.text, completed: false, dateCreated: new Date()} ).save()
            .then((newTask) => {
                console.log('The new exercise created is: ', newTask);
                res.redirect('user/:_id/tasklist');
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                next(err);   // most likely to be db error.
            });
    }
});
```

** tasklist.hbs, POST add button near the top. Need to double check the route here and for the tasklist route

```
<h1>EXERCISES</h1>
<div class="taskinfo">
<div class="addtask">
    <form method="POST" action="/tasks/user/{{user.id}}/tasklist/add" class="add_form">
        <input id="addtask_text" name="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter an exercise" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{user._id}}">
        <input class="addtask_button" type="submit" value="ADD Exercise">
    </form>
</div>

<div class="messages">
    {{#if messages}}
        <p class="error_msg">{{messages.error}}</p>
        <p class="info_msg">{{messages.info}}</p>
    {{/if}}
</div>

<div class="tasklist">
    {{#each tasks}}
        <p>{{@tasklist}}: <a href="/user/{{user.id}}/tasklist/{{this._id}}">{{this.text}}</a></p>


        <form action="/user/{{user._id}}/tasklist/done" method="POST" class="done_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{this._id}}">
            <input class="done_button" type="submit" name="done" value="Done">
        </form>

        <form action="/user/{{user._id}}/tasklist/delete" method="POST" class="delete_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{this._id}}">
            <input class="delete_button" type="submit" name="done" value="Delete">
        </form>
    {{else}}
        <p>There are no exercises. Time to create a list!</p>
    {{/each}}
```

I receive a 404 error because the new task needs to connect with a user's id and their tasklist. Here's my github repo:https://github.com/jhchiu1/healthapp

Comment: So, to access tasklist.hbs page from the browser, does the url look like example.com/user/12345/tasklist ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! Here's the url for the 404 page: http://127.0.0.1:3000/tasks/user//tasklist/add . In between "user" and tasklist" in that url should be a user id for that user in the db.

Comment: Here's the url for the user's exercise list page: http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/5a2ed6db4455d101dec6f212/tasklist?_id=5a2ed6db4455d101dec6f212

Comment: User's exercise list page: http://127.0.0.1:3000/user/5a2ed6db4455d101dec6f212/tasklist?_id=5a2ed6db4455d101dec6f212  . This page is functioning since the tasklist is connected to that user's id. I need something similar for the correct route to add an exercise to that user's tasklist.

Comment: No wonder, you didn't pass `user.id` in your `res.render()`. All your other forms must have `user.id` null also in that case. The solution will be either passing `user.id` in your `res.render()`, or take it from the URL string. How about the `{{user._id}}` though? Are they null also?

Comment: Isn't res.render() only used when you GET data from your db. I believe you need to use res.redirect() for data POSTs

Comment: `res.render()` is for rendering your page as the function name suggests, and in POST routes it's probably a better practice to use `res.redirect()` so no problems there. I mean, in your `router.get('/user/:_id/tasklist')` function you didn't put the `user.id` into the `res.render()`. That is most likely the reason that it's empty in the form.

Comment: Are you speaking of /* POST new exercise */ function in tasks.js?

Comment: I'm talking about the `res.render()` in /* GET home page with all incomplete exercises */ in tasks.js

Comment: Basically, I am unsure how to properly include a user's id when adding a task to their Exercise List, thus, an error appears. I need to figure out the proper URL

Comment: Ignore the /*GET all incomplete exercises */ ... I can figure that out once I figure out the "POST / ADD exercise" function.

Comment: // GET info about 1 client, connect to their exercise list//
router.get('/user/:_id/tasklist', function(req, res, next) {

    Task.find( { user :  req.params._id})
        .then( (docs) => {
            if (docs) {
                res.render('tasklist', { user_id: req.user._id, tasks : docs });

            } else {
                res.status(404);
                next(Error("User not found"));
            }
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            next(err);
        });

Comment: ^^ This allows access to a client's tasklist. I need to do something similar in order to add an exercise to their exercise list. I'm using task/exercise and tasklist/exercise list interchangeably, btw.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `user.id` to `user_id`. I just noticed when you render your tasklist from `index.js` you already passed the user's ID as `user_id`. But instead of `user_id`, you tried to access it with `user.id`.

`res.render('tasklist', { user_id: req.user._id, tasks : docs }); //index.js`

```
<form method="POST" action="/tasks/user/{{user_id}}/tasklist/add" class="add_form">
        <input id="addtask_text" name="text" type="text" placeholder="Enter an exercise" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="_id" value="{{user_id}}">
        <input class="addtask_button" type="submit" value="ADD Exercise">
</form>
```

If this fails, change the tasklist `res.render()`'s `user_id` into `req.params._id` like so:

```
res.render('tasklist', { user_id: req.params._id, tasks : docs });
```

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both, however, no progress though.

Comment: Is it still 404 and `user_id` being empty again after changing the form action?